# copy_history or load_history not showing failure activity in snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm copying data from a source to a snowflake table directly using ADF.

When snowpipe fails due to some data issues I'm not getting any failure record in `copy_history` or `load_history` with failure status. Does anyone know why I'm not seeing any failure record?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints are:

When you query the COPY_HISTORY() table-function (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html):

1. COPY_HISTORY() makes only use of the last 14 days
2. You are using the START_TIME / END_TIME-parameters of COPY_HISTORY() and set a time range where no query failed

When you query the COPY_HISTORY-View in your account (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/copy_history.html):

1. There can be a latency of 2 hours
2. You only see objects for which the current role for the session has access privileges. This means your role also has to have access-privileges on the table.

When you query the LOAD_HISTORY()-View (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/load_history.html):

1. You also just see the last 14 days
2. The history is deleted when your table is dropped
3. You only see the last 10.000 events
4. There are only COPY INTO commands that completed (with or without error) - probably the error aborts the execution and thus it's not completed.

I think it's about the 2 hours latency or access privilege-thing.

One more tip: You can try to run the COPY INTO-command in VALIDATION_MODE. Maybe this gives you more information

```
COPY INTO table VALIDATION_MODE = 'RETURN_ERRORS' FILES=('myFile.csv');
```

Comment: I can see success load in COPY_HISTORY but not failure one's.

Comment: Yes but: 1) Did you wait some time with querying after your copy failed? 2) Did your query complete? In my opinion there is a difference between "completing with failure" and "aborted because of failure and thus not completed". If it's the second alternative, the records are not shown.